# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' how resolve this problem

Tags: python, mysql

Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' how resolve this problem

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host = "localhost",
   user = "username",
   password = "username"
)
print(mydb)
```

Comment: Without deep dive it looks like you are missing the DB name

Comment: refer this url https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysqldb-connection-python/  @sim